# "Camera Error 1004" Error while taking pictures with Android Camera

Tags: java, android, camera

I am developing two applications as Server and Client. Server application takes pictures repeatedly and send them to the client application over tcp socket.
In onPictureTaken function, I encode the byte array in base64 and write the result string to the output stream. However, after taking some picture, camera gives an error as "Camera Error 1004".

At first, I thought there was a memory leak, and it was. But now, I resolved it by doing the encoding in parts. Still, camera gives that error after some time. What does this error mean?

Here is the code of the function :

```
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Taking picture of " + data.length + " bytes.");
    String imageXML = "<image>" + encodeTobase64(data) + "</image>"; 
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter;
    try {
        bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out));
        bufferedWriter.write(Utils.packServerMessage(imageXML));
        bufferedWriter.flush();
        Log.e(TAG, "Picture is sent.");
        isReady = true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Picture cannot be sent.");
        isError = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `out`? If it is some stream to a server, why are you doing network I/O on the main application thread?

Comment: out is an outputStream and this function belongs to a class that runs in different thread.

Answer (score 0):

> this function belongs to a class that runs in different thread.

Java has methods (not functions), and classes do not run on threads (methods do).

If this is [the `onPictureTaken()` of your `Camera.PictureCallback`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.PictureCallback.html), that is called on the main application thread.

Comment: I call all functions of the class in a different thread. So, onPictureTaken() is also called in a different thread. The problem is not about this issue.